# iOS - Present/Show ViewController while content underneath remains interactive

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, wkwebview, wkwebviewconfiguration

I'd like to present/show a `ViewController` (let's call it *ViewController2*) that is somehow hidden (or have a 0 size) and, after some time, it'll be resized to a specific size (or fullscreen) meanwhile keeping the content of the `ViewController` (let's call it *ViewController1*) presenting/showing it interactive.

[image: ViewControllers flow]

---

Just to give some more context on *why* I want to do that.

I'm trying to load a `WKWebView` in the background and, ideally, would like to present the `ViewController` **only** when the webview is fully loaded. Unfortunately, [iOS seems to "pause" javascript evaluation and its timers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31169884/wkwebkit-javascript-execution-when-not-attached-to-a-view-hierarchy) after a very short time [when the webview is not presented to the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53482566/wkwebview-doesnt-run-javascript-when-on-background).

I can confirm code like `setTimeout` stop working when the webview is attached to a ViewController which is not presented to the user and resumes working when that controller is presented/shown.

My idea here is, presenting the controller right away but somehow hidden (while keeping the app interactive) and when getting the right signal from the webview, I'd show/resize it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it using Xcode 11 then present your view controller modally.

```
 let changevc = UIViewController() // change this code as this is  your view controller with edit button
 changeVC.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic // .popover
 self.present(changeVC, animated: true, completion: nil
```

You can try different types of modals from this site and use whichever you find best.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimodalpresentationstyle

Comment: Presenting another view controller modally will not let you interact with the view controller from where you are presenting the modal controller. But Andre wants that to be interactive.